# cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'Range<String.Index>

Tags: swift, function

Trying to make a function in Swift Spritekit, this is how it looks like:

```
func card_vals(card_value_set: [Int], card_set: [String]) {
        var card_value_set = card_value_set
        var card_set = card_set
        for i in card_set {
            var j = Int(i[0])
                card_value_set.append(j)
            }
    }
```

In simple words, the function is taking a card_set, looking like ["3C", "4D"] which is a Str list, and the card_value_set should look like [3,4], which is a Int list.
However, I am getting the following error:

```
cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'Range<String.Index>
```

Any help to erase this error?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to the wrapped with String

`i[0]`  return character and there is no initializer of Int type for accepting character type.

```
func card_vals(card_value_set: [Int], card_set: [String]) {
    var card_value_set = card_value_set
    var card_set = card_set
    for i in card_set {
        if let first = i.first, let intData = Int(String(first)) {
            card_value_set.append(intData)
        }
    }
}
```

Or you can also do this

```
var j = Int(String(i[0])) ?? 0
```